# How do the iterators V and E in igraph using R work?

Tags: r, iterator, graph-theory, igraph

I've looked through the source for V and E and I'm not really sure how they work.
Here's the code for V:

```
> V
function (graph)
{
    if (!is.igraph(graph)) {
        stop("Not a graph object")
    }
    vc <- vcount(graph)
    if (vc == 0) {
        res <- numeric()
    }
    else {
        res <- 0:(vc - 1)
    }
    class(res) <- "igraph.vs"
    ne <- new.env()
    assign("graph", graph, envir = ne)
    attr(res, "env") <- ne
    res
}
```

I'm not really sure what purpose the calls to assign and attr serve here.
Does assigning graph create a new copy of graph? How efficient/inefficient is this? That is, how many copies of graph does this generate say in code like:

```
V(g)$someattr <- somevector
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I haven't used `igraph` so can't answer your general question, but usually in R when you see apparently superfluous environments being created and assigned into, the purpose is to *prevent* a copy from being made. I'm guessing this is what let's `V(g)` refer back to and modify `g` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693121/workaround-for-pointers-in-r)

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. It does allow you to modify `g`.

Comment: @starflyer: did you find a definite answer? If so, would you mind posting it? You got me curious ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When generating a vertex sequence with `V`, the calls to `assign` and `attr` store a copy of the graph that was used to create the sequence along with the vertex sequence object, itself. This way when you do something like `V(g)$color = 'blue'`, the vertex sequence can be conveniently evaluated in the context of this copy of `g`. This is clear if you inspect one of the methods available for the `igraph.vs` class.

```
> methods(class='igraph.vs')
[1] [.igraph.vs     [<-.igraph.vs   $.igraph.vs     $<-.igraph.vs   print.igraph.vs

> `$.igraph.vs`
function (x, name) 
{
    get.vertex.attribute(get("graph", attr(x, "env")), name, 
        x)
}
<environment: namespace:igraph>
```

Here it is clear that the `$` indexing operation will get evaluated in the context of the graph environment that was used to create the vertex sequence.

You bring up a good point though that this *does* create multiple copies of the graph (which presumably get garbage collected, but it's still good to be aware of). This is easily demonstrated if you modify attributes of a graph `g`, after you have already created a vertex sequence `vs = V(g)`. The attribute is updated in `g`, but not in the copy of `g` that is stored in the environment attached to `vs`.

```
> g = graph(c(0:1), directed=F)
> g = set.vertex.attribute(g, 'color', value='blue')
> vs = V(g)
> vs$color
[1] "blue" "blue"
> g = set.vertex.attribute(g, 'color', value='red')
> V(g)$color
[1] "red" "red"
> vs$color
[1] "blue" "blue"
```